# Types of effective masses

Tags: mass, semiconductor-physics

I understand the existence of effective mass for electrons, light hole, heavy hole, and split-off.

But how can they be different from the density of states effective mass of conduction and valence bands?

are all semiconductors have heavy and light holes?

Comment: There is no requirement that there be light and heavy holes. One might need to find a non-cubic-symmetry semiconductor.

Comment: Non-cubic semiconductor? Just a few examples: hexagonal GaN and SiC, bi-layer graphene, MoS2, WSe2

Comment: @engineer -indeed. I guess my attempt to point that way was far too subtle. Now, we just need a nice triclinic semiconductor - that would really show some interesting effects.

Comment: aah I see. Thanks @JonCuster and @/engineer. But what is the difference between, say density of states effective mass of valence band with effective mass of heavy holes/ light holes?